# How do I put the data from navigation in the state?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

I make a setData (dataOther) but the data is not passed on to the state data, and the error "undefined is not an object" is displayed when I put the data in the value of the components.

What am I doing wrong? How can I put the data from the other screen in the state and be able to render it on the screen?

My code:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      View,
      FlatList,
      ActivityIndicator,
    } from "react-native";
    
    import { 
        KeyboardAvoidingView, 
        ScrollView, 
        TextInput, 
        ViewButton, 
        Button, 
        ButtonClean, 
        Loading, 
        Text 
    } from './styles';
    
    import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import FormRow from "../../components/FormRow";
    
    import firebase from "@firebase/app";
    import "@firebase/database";
    
    export default function QuestList({ navigation }) {
        const [data, setData] = useState({});
        const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([
            {...blankQuest}
        ]);
    
        const dataOther = navigation.getParam('dataItem');
        const input = navigation.getParam('inputs');
    
        const blankQuest = { quests: '', ans: '' };
        
    
        useEffect(() => {
            setData(dataOther);
            console.log(dataOther)
        }, []);
    
        function handleUpdate() {
            const db = firebase.database();
            db
            .ref(`/questionnaires/${dataOther.id}`)
            .set(dataOther);
        }
    
      return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1}} enabled>
                    <StatusBar style="#6ca2f7" />
                    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 10 }}>
                            <FormRow first>
                                <Text>{dataOther.title}</Text>
                            </FormRow>
    
                            <FormRow>
                                    <Text>{dataOther.creator.creatorAuthor}</Text>
                                    <TextInput 
                                        style={{marginBottom: 20}}
                                        placeholderTextColor= '#808080'
                                        value={dataOther.creator.user}
                                        onChangeText={setData}
                                        placeholder='Usuário'
                                        multiline={true}
                                    />
                            </FormRow>
    
                            <FormRow>
                                <Text>{dataOther.date.dateCreator}</Text>
                                    <TextInput
                                        style={{marginBottom: 20}}
                                        placeholderTextColor= '#808080'
                                        value={dataOther.date.dateUser}
                                        onChangeText={setData}
                                        placeholder='Data das repostas'
                                    />
                        </FormRow>
    
                        {
                            dataOther.customField.map((q, id) => (
                                <FormRow key={id}>
                                    <Text>{q.quests}</Text>
                                    <TextInput
                                        style={{marginBottom: 20}}
                                        placeholderTextColor= '#808080'
                                        value={q.ans}
                                        onChangeText={setData}
                                        placeholder='Resposta'
                                        multiline={true}
                                    />
                                </FormRow>
                                
    
                            ))
                        }
    
                        <ViewButton>
                            <Button
                                title='Salvar'
                                onPress={() => {handleUpdate()}}
                            />
                        </ViewButton>
                            
                    </ScrollView>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      );
    }

Result of console.log(dataOther):

    Object {
      "creator": Object {
        "creatorAuthor": "Alisson",
        "user": "",
      },
      "customField": Array [
        Object {
          "ans": "Resposta 1",
          "quests": "Pergunta 1?",
        },
        Object {
          "ans": "Resposta 2",
          "quests": "Pergunta 2",
        },
        Object {
          "ans": "Resposta 3",
          "quests": "Pergunta 3",
        },
      ],
      "date": Object {
        "dateCreator": "01/01/2021",
        "dateUser": "",
      },
      "id": "-MQxtMmc_K7rDIgutcNC",
      "title": "Google",
    }
```

Error message:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.creator.user')

This error is located at:
in NavigationContainer (at App.js:10)
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
- node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue

- [native code]:null in flushedQueue
- [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

Edit:
Component on the other screen where I'm passing the data:

```
<FlatList
                    data={[...data, { isLast: true }]}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        item.isLast
                            ? <AddQuestCard
                                isFirstColumn={isEven(index)}
                                onNavigate={() => navigation.navigate('Main')} />
                            : <QuestCard 
                                    quest={item}
                                    isFirstColumn={isEven(index)}
                                    onNavigate={() => navigation.navigate('QuestAnswer', { dataItem: item, ...data2 })}
                                />
                           
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    numColumns={2}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    ListHeaderComponent={props => (<ViewTop/>)}
                    ListFooterComponent={props => (<ViewBottom/>)}
            />
```

Comment: is dataOther undefined when you console.log?

Comment: the value of `dataOther` is `undefined` at the point when you're trying to access properties like `dataOther.title` and `dataOther.creator.creatorAuthor` -- try checking that `dataOther` has the value you're expecting.. if not, it's an issue of `navitgation.getParam()` not returning what you're expecting.

Comment: @jnotelddim Yes, the data is coming, but it is not going to the state

Comment: @Bélgica It is not. Data is being displayed on the console

Comment: Can you please add the following information to your Question: 1) the full error text, and 2) the value of the `dataOther` object if you `console.log(dataOther)` on the line after it's defined (line 32 or whatever)?

Comment: @jnotelddim Added

Comment: So it looks like the error  ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.creator.user')

This error is located at: in NavigationContainer (at App.js:10)``` is coming from a completely different file. Can you share the contents of `App.js` ?

Comment: Please, on useEffect hook console log this: navigation.getParam('dataItem')

Comment: @Bélgica  The result was the same as I put in the question

Comment: @jnotelddim 
import React from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import Routes from "./src/routes";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Routes />
    </>
  );
}

Comment: @jnotelddim I put in question the FlatList component in which I am passing the data through navigation

Comment: @Bélgica 

Object {
  "creator": Object {
    "creatorAuthor": "",
    "user": "",
  },
  "customField": Array [
    Object {
      "quests": "Ko",
    },
  ],
  "date": Object {
    "dateCreator": "",
    "dateUser": "",
  },
  "id": "-MQxzqDNUBTKw06VN3M8",
  "title": "Testando",
}

Comment: I don't understand why you setData but you never use data. Instead you are using dataOther constant in all.

Comment: @Bélgica Regardless of that the error still happens

Comment: Set dataOther as a state instead a constant and tell me...

Comment: @Bélgica Like this?
const [data, setData] = useState(navigation.getParam('dataItem'));
Or like that?
const [data, setData] = useState(dataOther);

Comment: First. And tell me if works.

Comment: @Bélgica It worked, but an error happens when I type in the field. Do I have to put it in a separate state? How I do?

Comment: Sorry, what error?

Comment: @Bélgica It looks like it resets everything within the data
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.creator.creatorAuthor')

Comment: Mmm how its possible? if u can screenshot it would be better

Comment: @Bélgica Unfortunately, there's no way to send this around. Unfortunately, there is no way to send it around here. But basically, it is a questionnaire creation application, and these fields must be empty for another user to answer. Because of this the input needs a setData over there

Comment: I would really want to help you but i don´t know yet where is the problem

Comment: @Bélgica When I type in these empty inputs, this error happens

Comment: react-navigation version please?

Comment: @vijeeshin "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",